# new dGrid by passing dom element not id

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I see the example online showing attach by id

```
var grid = new Grid({ columns: columns }, 'grid'); // attach to a DOM id
```

But I'm wondering if I can pass a dom element instead.

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
var grid = new Grid({ columns: columns }, element);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes I confirmed that you can pass it a DOM element

http://jsfiddle.net/w7amofpf/

```
var element = document.getElementById('grid');

var grid = new Grid({
    store: store,
    columns: {
        num: "id",
        ipaddress: "IP address"                
    }            
}, element);
```